# Electronic Data Collection in West Africa (with no internet / cell network)

Tags: android, mobile, couchbase-lite

I work for a nonprofit healthcare organization called Last Mile Health in Liberia, West Africa. We train community health workers (CHWs) to provide treatment to patients in rural villages, where there is no internet or cell service.

We're working on a pilot project where we plan on equipping our CHWs with smartphones (or some other device) to do two things:

1. CHWs can collect data on their phones, and can then "dump" their data onto the devices of their supervisors, who will then dump the data into a central web-based database. The CHW-to-supervisor data transfer will happen in-person, in the field.
2. CHWs can generate custom views and reports of the data that they collect, right on their devices (e.g. after she has collected data on ages of people living in each household, the CHW can run a summary report that shows her how many children, men, and women are in her village).

Right now I'm thinking that the solution may be to build Android data collection apps that store data locally (maybe using Couchbase-Lite or SQLite) on smartphones, and then use WiFi Direct to transfer data between devices. However, I'm not an android developer (my background is in PhP/MySQL/js), so I could use some advice. Does anyone have thoughts on what the best possible solution stack could look like (hardware + software)? Biggest constraint on hardware is that it has to have as long a battery life as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developers of Couchbase Lite, and your use case is something we built it to handle.

The [replication protocol](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html) is designed for peer to peer, and is also used for sync from peers to the cloud. The face-to-face data handoff you describe is definitely something we do.

[There is a thread on our mailing list about p2p peer discovery, which is the part Couchbase Lite doesn't handle for you.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mobile-couchbase/peer%2420to%2420peer/mobile-couchbase/K6lZ-YD87VI/g6h4fkdisNAJ) WiFi Direct should be a good way to connect the devices. Once the devices are connected, Couchbase Lite can sync automatically.